# how to get the id of element on click using jquery

Tags: jquery

On First Click event i am hiding the Upper Layer image and after that i need to get the id of below image

```
$( ".overlay_image" ).click(function( event ) 
{
    event.preventDefault();
    $( this ).hide("slow"); 
}
```

Comment: Could you provide an example of the HTML/element structure?

Comment: <ul id="image_list">
<li>
<a><div class="overlay_image" id="front"></div></a>
 <a>  <img src="list1.jpg" alt="Image1" class="visible" id="firstCard"></a>
            </li>
            <li>
                <div class="overlay_image"></div>
                <img src="list2.jpg" alt="Image2">
            </li>
              <li>
                <div class="overlay_image"></div>
                <img src="list3.jpg" alt="Image3">
            </li>
            <li>
                <div class="overlay_image"></div>
                <img src="list4.jpg" alt="Image4">
            </li>
        </ul>

Answer (score 0):

If the images.overlay_image are in the same parent container this will do it.

```
$( ".overlay_image" ).click(function( event ) 
{
    event.preventDefault();
    $( this ).hide("slow");
    var nextOverlayImage = $( this ).next('.overlay_image'); 
}
```